# Multitenant signon issue with asp.net core

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I have enabled my application as multi-tenant and deployed it on one Azure tenant. Now there are 3 tenants with ADs I want all users from these ADs to be able to login to my app.
2 Ads are working fine but for one Ad user I am getting below error.
What to do?

Need admin approval
Tenant1
Tenant1 needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.
Have an admin account? Sign in with that account
Return to the application without granting consent.

Comment: have you allowed permission on your portal for that application?

Comment: I am not sure about the settings. How do I do it?

Comment: Take a look and feel free to share if you have any more query! Thank You

Comment: Yes. One is working... What all permissions are required?

Comment: What you wanted to access depend on that. If related to application resource access then application permission if user need to access any API resource then need delegated permission for that specific API.If you have still any query feel free to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah correct, You may not assign permission for that. To allow this consent you need to have permission on your portal. As you many know there are two kind of permission

**1. [Delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions)** Required when user need to access resources.

**2. [Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions)** When application request for accessing resource.

**Set Permission on Portal:**

You can set your application and delegated permission from azure portal.

**Steps**

1. *Login in to Azure portal*
2. *click on Active directory*
3. *App Registrations*
4. *Select Your apps*
5. *Settings*
6. *Required permissions*

see the below screen shot for better idea

[image]

> **Note:** Particularly for your case I would suggest you to check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#consent-and-multi-tier-applications)

If you still have any problem feel free to share here in comment. Thank you.

Comment: @RAhulApte If my answer helpful you could mark it by clicking on the checkbox beside your question to help others. Thank you.